# if else statement using char[] containing multiple special characters C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, char

I am trying to build an if else statement using char[] for special characters...I would like for my If statement to run if TextBox1 contains all the characters...if not then the else statement will execute...I am having trouble running the IF statement when I am using multiple special character...any help is much appreciated...please see below examples:

When using one special character (char[] chars = {'^'};) the below code will run...

Text entered into TextBox1 is: 
**%TXSMITH^SMITH$JOHN^1411 MAIN CIRCLE^? ;95651501425264=160919780101?%**

C#

```
char[] chars = {'^'};
string characters = new string(chars);

if (TextBox1.Text.Contains(characters))
{
    string s = TextBox1.Text;
    int beglastname = s.IndexOf("^");
    int endlastname = s.IndexOf("$", beglastname + 1);
    string lastname = s.Substring(beglastname + 1, endlastname - beglastname - 1);

    int begfirstname = s.IndexOf("$");
    int endfirstname = s.IndexOf("^", endlastname + 1);
    string firstname = s.Substring(endlastname + 1, endfirstname - begfirstname - 1);

    int begaddress = s.IndexOf("^", endlastname + 1);
    int endaddress = s.IndexOf("^", endfirstname + 1);
    string address = s.Substring(endfirstname + 1, endaddress - begaddress - 1);

    int begdob = s.IndexOf("=", begaddress + 1);
    int enddob = s.IndexOf("%", endaddress + 1);
    string dob = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("?%", endaddress + 1) - 8, 8); // DOB field is always 8 characters, should be doing the substring backwards from the padding character 8 characters in length
    string categories = firstname + " " + lastname + " " + address + " " + dob + Environment.NewLine;
    File.AppendAllText(@"C:\temp\test\dl_test2.txt", categories);
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("error_page_c.aspx");
}
```

However...when I add multiple special characters (char[] chars = { '^', '$', '=', '%', ';', '?' };) my code will not run...

Text entered into TextBox1 is: 
**%TXSMITH^SMITH$JOHN^1411 MAIN CIRCLE^? ;95651501425264=160919780101?%**

C#

```
char[] chars = { '^', '$', '=', '%', ';', '?' };;
string characters = new string(chars);

if (TextBox1.Text.Contains(characters))
{
    string s = TextBox1.Text;
    int beglastname = s.IndexOf("^");
    int endlastname = s.IndexOf("$", beglastname + 1);
    string lastname = s.Substring(beglastname + 1, endlastname - beglastname - 1);

    int begfirstname = s.IndexOf("$");
    int endfirstname = s.IndexOf("^", endlastname + 1);
    string firstname = s.Substring(endlastname + 1, endfirstname - begfirstname - 1);

    int begaddress = s.IndexOf("^", endlastname + 1);
    int endaddress = s.IndexOf("^", endfirstname + 1);
    string address = s.Substring(endfirstname + 1, endaddress - begaddress - 1);

    int begdob = s.IndexOf("=", begaddress + 1);
    int enddob = s.IndexOf("%", endaddress + 1);
    string dob = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("?%", endaddress + 1) - 8, 8); // DOB field is always 8 characters, should be doing the substring backwards from the padding character 8 characters in length
    string categories = firstname + " " + lastname + " " + address + " " + dob + Environment.NewLine;
    File.AppendAllText(@"C:\temp\test\dl_test2.txt", categories);
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("error_page_c.aspx");
}
```

Comment: The easiest way it to use a regular expression.

Comment: You will need to loop through one of the sets of characters and set a flag to true if they all exist in the other characters set.

Comment: @Moo-Juice This looks like EDI/HL7 actually :)

Comment: Or some form of card swipe data.  Credit cards look very similar.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a little bit of Linq, for example:

```
if (characters.All(c => TextBox1.Text.Contains(c.ToString()))
{
    ...
}
```

But it may be better to refactor your code to make judicious use of [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or perhaps a regular expression.

Here's an example using a regular expression:

```
string s = "%TXSMITH^SMITH$JOHN^1411 MAIN CIRCLE^? ;95651501425264=160919780101?%";
string pattern = @"^%.*?\^(?<ln>.*?)\$(?<fn>.+?)\^(?<addr>.+?)\^.*=\d{4}(?<dob>\d+)\?%$";
var match = Regex.Match(s, pattern);
if (match.Success)
{
    string categories = 
        String.Join(" ", 
                    match.Groups["fn"], 
                    match.Groups["ln"], 
                    match.Groups["addr"], 
                    match.Groups["dob"]) 
        + Environment.NewLine;
    // categories == "JOHN SMITH 1411 MAIN CIRCLE 19780101"
}
```

Comment: It's not clear from the OP's question, but there's a newline character between the first `?` and the `;`  You need to use `RegexOptions.Singleline` to match on that.  But this is otherwise exactly what I was about to post.

Comment: @Bobson It looks like a space to me. If you check the markdown systax, it's all on one line.

Comment: Hmm, good point.  It probably depends on the card reader as to whether it's interpreted as a newline or a space, but he definitely used a space.

Answer (score 1):

The `string.Contains()` method returns `true` only if there's an **exact** match.

To check if a string has at least one occurence for each char out of a given set, you must check them one by one, e.g. with the `String.IndexOf(...)` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check it this way:

```
bool ContainsAllChars = true;
foreach (char NextChar in chars)
    if (TextBox1.Text.IndexOf(NextChar) == -1)
    {
        ContainsAllChars = false;
        break;
    }
if (ContainsAllChars)
    ...
```

I don't think you can use IndexOfAny here because it looks for occurence of ANY of the array characters and returns -1 only if NONE of them are present.

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression will match your pattern.

```
public bool IsTheStringIWant(string s)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex("%.*\\^.*\\$.*\\^.*\\^\\?.*;.*=.*\\?%");
    return regex.IsMatch(s);
}
```